# Is there a way to find the roots of a 4th order polynomial that is faster than using Sympy's nroot()?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, numerical-methods

I'm trying to solve a 4th order polynomial with complex coefficients i.e.

```
-0.678916793992528*w^4 + 9207096.65180878*i*w^3 
+ 1.47445911372677e+15*w^2 - 1.54212540689566e+21*i*w 
+ 2.70530138119032e+26
```

The end goal of this code will be solving this polynomial at least 100,000 times, each time with different coefficients, so I'd like the code to be quick and efficient.  I've been using sympy.nroots() to get the roots but according to %timeit it takes about 9.6 ms per loop which is quiet slow compared to numpy.roots() which takes 60 µs per loop.  However I can't use numpy.roots() since it doesn't handle complex coefficients well and has consistently solved the roots of this polynomial incorrectly.  Using sympy.solve() is even slower at 122 ms per loop.

One thing I have thought of to try and speed up this process is the fact that I really only need the imaginary components of the roots, specifically the most negative imaginary component, but I'm not sure if that can be leveraged into a faster run time for this code.

My questions are is there another function I can use for root finding that might be faster?  Or is there a different root finding method I can write that will be faster?  Finally is there a way to only solve for the complex valued roots, and would that be faster?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but I also wonder, are you over-optimizing your code? If it takes 10 ms per root and you need 100,000 of them, you can solve your whole problem in about 17 mins. That is probably faster than writing this question and waiting for an answer and certainly faster than writing your own root finder. But of course it would be interesting to know why some root finders are faster/better than others....

Comment: In the example, the coefficients of the even powers are real, and those of the odd powers are pure imaginary.  Is that true in general for the different coefficients that you are interested in?

Comment: Can you please explain why `np.roots` isn't good for you? I just tested it and it works great.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785/is-there-a-general-formula-for-solving-4th-degree-equations-quartic) help?

Comment: Sympy uses the arbitrarily precision mpmath as backend for numerical computations. Arbitrarily precision is expected to be slower than numpy's fixed precision.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I believe the example holds in general after spot checking some other cases, so even powers should be real and odd powers should be imaginary.

Comment: @iliar When checking the roots that numpy calculates against Wolfram Alpha it only calculates 2 correctly and sometimes it gets none of the roots correct.  Sympy has consistently gotten them correct.  In the above example numpy gets the roots: (4.60399640e+07+6254097.84852026j, -4.60399640e+07+6254097.84852023j, 2.32590426e-10+1206273.08238215j, -1.96150674e-11 -153018.04896671j) while Wolfram gets the roots: (-4.603996402512×10^7 + 6.25409784852×10^j,-153018.04896671j, 1.206273082382×10^6j, 4.603996402512×10^7 + 6.25409784852×10^6j).

Comment: If you display the python result with the full available 16 digits (I've adapted my answer to this end) and scale both real and imaginary part to have the same power of 10, then comparing the available digits of WA with these will reveal that both results are identical up to that point. There is nothing incorrect in the numpy roots. Using another CAS (Magma) with 28 digits precision finds the roots as `1206273.08238215110391423005*i, 46039964.02512096802210723994+6254097.84852025581342653031*i, -46039964.02512096802210723994+6254097.84852025581342653033*i, -153018.04896671357382543598*i`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I've done some digging and it is true in general, that the even powers will be real and the odd terms will be purely imaginary.

Comment: That means you can make the substitution `w = i*z`, and get a polynomial for `z` that has *real* coefficients.  Solve that for `z`, then multiply the result by `i` to get `w`.

Comment: This is tangential to your post, but you could use python's multiprocessing library to parallelize your root calculating, which would speed up your program quite a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not get a much better result than the one of `np.root` in double precision floating point numbers. Evaluating a polynomial close to a root involves a lot of catastrophic cancellations.

Trying out your example with the routines of `numpy` gives the roots as

```py
def print_Carr(z):
    for zz in z: print(">>> % 22.17e %+.17ej"%(zz.real, zz.imag))

p=np.array([-0.678916793992528, 9207096.65180878j, 1.47445911372677e+15, -1.54212540689566e+21j, 2.70530138119032e+26])
z=np.roots(p); print_Carr(z)
>>>  4.60399640251209885e+07 +6.25409784852022864e+06j
>>> -4.60399640251209214e+07 +6.25409784852025378e+06j
>>>  6.97016694994478896e-13 +1.20627308238215139e+06j
>>>  5.23825344503222243e-11 -1.53018048966713541e+05j
```

These are rather large values for polynomial evaluation. The evaluated values at these roots are

```py
print_Carr(np.polyval(p,z))
>>> -3.48222204464332800e+15 +2.82412997568102400e+15j
>>>  5.73769835033395200e+15 -1.64254152287846400e+15j
>>> -4.12316860416000000e+11 +1.37984933104284096e+09j
>>>  6.87194767360000000e+10 -1.04451799855962357e+11j
```

This looks rather bad for residuals, however changes in the last bits of the mantissa of the the roots introduce a large absolute change of the values. Remember that the exact roots (for the given coefficients) is somewhere in-between the floating point numbers. The influence of these changes on the polynomial value can be estimated by replacing coefficients and roots with their absolute values, as `mu*|p|(|z|)` is an estimate of the error of floating point evaluation.

```py
print_Carr(np.polyval(abs(p),abs(z)) *2**-52)
>>>  1.63036010254646300e+15 +0.00000000000000000e+00j
>>>  1.63036010254645625e+15 +0.00000000000000000e+00j
>>>  9.53421868314746094e+11 +0.00000000000000000e+00j
>>>  1.20139515277909210e+11 +0.00000000000000000e+00j
```

The residuals are almost in the range of these bounds.

Changing the last mantissa bits of the root approximations or the polynomial coefficients has an influence that can be estimated via the derivatives at the root locations

```py
print_Carr(abs(np.polyval(np.polyder(p),z))*(2**-52*abs(z)))
>>>  1.38853576300226150e+15 +0.00000000000000000e+00j
>>>  1.38853576300225050e+15 +0.00000000000000000e+00j
>>>  5.30242273857438416e+11 +0.00000000000000000e+00j
>>>  6.77504690635207825e+10 +0.00000000000000000e+00j
```

again demonstrating that any change in more than the last two mantissa bits will drastically increase the residual.

To remove the possible imprecision of the "eigenvalues of the companion matrix" in the implementation of `np.roots`, apply "root polishing" by one step of the Newton method and recalculate the residuals,

```py
z = z - np.polyval(p,z)/np.polyval(np.polyder(p),z); print_Carr(z)
>>>  4.60399640251209661e+07 +6.25409784852025565e+06j
>>> -4.60399640251209661e+07 +6.25409784852025472e+06j
>>>  1.00974195868289511e-28 +1.20627308238215116e+06j
>>>  0.00000000000000000e+00 -1.53018048966713570e+05j
print_Carr(np.polyval(p,z))
>>>  6.74825261547520000e+13 -7.41139556597760000e+13j
>>>  1.55993212190720000e+13 -1.15513145425920000e+14j
>>>  2.74877906944000000e+11 +1.99893600285358499e-07j
>>>  0.00000000000000000e+00 +0.00000000000000000e+00j
```

There actually is a reduction in the residual by one or two decimal places, indicating that this is almost the best achievable with this floating point data type.

Thus the new proposal for your task is to use `numpy.roots` with one Newton step for root polishing.

---

Finally compare with another multi-precision result

```py
from mpmath import mp
mp.dps = 20; mp.pretty = True;
mp.polyroots(p, maxsteps=20, extraprec=30) # prec=bits, dps=digits, 10bits=3digits
>>> [(0.0 - 153018.04896671356797j),
>>>  (0.0 + 1206273.0823821511478j),
>>>  (-46039964.025120967306 + 6254097.8485202553318j),
>>>  ( 46039964.025120967306 + 6254097.8485202553318j)]
```

The roots+Newton result is correct in the 15 leading digits, when counting position the same way for real and imaginary part.

Comment: Hi. After 100 newton iterations I get the following residuals:
`1.55993212e+13+1.15513145e+14j  6.74825262e+13+7.41139557e+13j
 -4.12316860e+11+0.00000000e+00j  0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j]` And it doesn't get smaller from iteration to iteration. It seems only the first 10 iterations or so make any impact. Can you explain why that happens?

Comment: That is why I included the scale computation. The floating point error while evaluating near the root is `mu* |p|(|z|)`, and if you consider the computed values, the residuals are actually a little smaller than that. The only way to change that is to make `mu` smaller than the `2^(-52)` of the `double` or `float64` type, that is, employ multi-precision data types like sympy does. This however sacrifices speed.

Comment: From the perturbation factor analysis using the derivative you can see that the uncertainty in the floating point coefficients will give a similar derivative bound, so if you do not get better coefficients as input, then the improvement due to higher precision in the output is quite meaningless.

Comment: sympy.nroots uses mpmath.polyroots internally, FWIW (see https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/52069d42f4d6df1811269f4bf8c00da93e02fae6/sympy/polys/polytools.py#L3586-L3587)